# Does this C++ casting to enum have problems?

Tags: c++, enums, casting

Given the following code:

```
enum Options
{
    Surf     = 0x01,
    Out      = 0x02
};

Options all = (Options) ( Surf | Out);
```

1. Does this casting have problems?
2. If this casting make sense, then why?

Based on my understanding, Options only defines two variables. How does the value 0x03 makes sense?

Comment: FYI:  You have an extra semicolon after `0x02` and you need a comma after `0x01`.

Comment: I have corrected the code based on your suggestions -- thank you

Comment: The only problem (apart from syntax errors) is the use of a C-Cast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does this casting have problems?

No.

> If this casting make sense, then why? Based on my understanding, Options only defines two variables, how the value 0x03 makes sense?

The enumeration type `Options` has two named enumerators, but the range of values that it represents is large enough that it can be used as a bitfield containing each of the enumerators.

In short:  yes, it is valid and well-defined to use an enumeration for a bitfield like this.

As requested in the comments to this answer, the formal language permitting this can be found in the C++ Standard (C++03 7.2/6):

> For an enumeration where *e<sub>min</sub>* is the smallest enumerator and *e<sub>max</sub>* is the largest, the values of the enumeration are the values of the underlying type in the range *b<sub>min</sub>* to *b<sub>max</sub>*, where *b<sub>min</sub>* and *b<sub>max</sub>* are, respectively, the smallest and largest values of the smallest bit-field that can store *e<sub>min</sub>* and *e<sub>max</sub>*.
>
> It is possible to define an enumeration that has values not defined by any of its enumerators.

There is some debate as to whether or not this is good style.  Certainly it can be argued that it is often assumed that an enumeration object can only store one of its enumerators, so code like this could be confusing and error-prone.

On the other hand, I would argue that it is usually quite obvious when an enumeration is intended for use as a bitfield.  Usually such an enumeration is named with an `Options` or `Flags` suffix or something similar.  Likewise, if each of the enumerators has a set value that is clearly a single set bit, that enumeration is probably intended for use as a bitfield.

Comment: @gravitron: this is not a matter of opinions. Enums in C++ were specifically *designed* to support that operation, it’s safe, it’s standard and it’s an established idiom. There’s nothing to disagree.

Comment: @gravitron:  You strongly disagree on what grounds?  Style?  Technical correctness?  Whether this is good style is debatable (I tend to think that it is perfectly acceptable).  Whether this is technically correct is not debatable.

Comment: Well... I'm with gravitron. I guess it depends on definition of "valid" and "makes sense". It's a style call, but I think it fails "make sense" for "casual reader of the code". I expect enums to be part of an enumeration! (But is it well-behavied, wrt to the language definition? Well ok yes.)

Comment: Really?  Please provide a source.  I am more of a C programmer than C++ and humbly retract my argument if that is true.  Specifically I would like to see a source stating that it's good practice to have a variable defined as an enum type storing a value that is not a member of said enum.

Comment: @gravitron:  I've added the reference to the answer.

Comment: @James thanks.  My gut reaction is "ew" but it's clear I have no argument.

Comment: @James, Now that's surprising! I didn't know that enums were designed to support those operations, even though it indeed makes sense. In C++, I'd still prefer `std::bitset` for that, however. I think...

Answer (score 1):

Q1> Yes.  You're using an enum when you seemingly want a bitmask.

Q2> You are correct, it doesn't make sense.  Using an enum implies that the variable all would be equal to one of the items in Options, not an or'd combination of multiple items..

Comment: Of course C++ enums are totally lame so it's hardly surprising when they get abused in this way.

Comment: @David, that's why we luckily have `enum class` in C++0x.

Comment: that said, there's no problem in defining an enum like that and then use it like `unsigned char myFlags = Surf | Out;` or something like that.

Comment: @Kos In 2011, C++ is reaching something approaching maturity.

Comment: @David: I'm not surprised with slow evolution of C++. It evolves slowly because it works. Priority #1 is to make it still work and not break compatibility, priority #2 is to make new features and **design them well and get feedback from compiler makers and target programmers before you_standarise**, hence the slow development.

Comment: @Kos No, I do understand that. I'm quite interested in the evolution of C++ and am reading Bjarne's book at the moment. I've followed C++0x a little. I don't like the language (a personal opinion) much but there's a lot to be learned from it. I can see the pros and cons for the slow considered standards based approach of C++ and the benevolent dictator approach perhaps best personified by Python.

Comment: Nice comment about Python, I cannot disagree. :) I used to dislike C++ too, but I've stopped C++ when I asked myself several times "could I design XYZ better in this language" and considering all circumstances I ended with a "no, there are problems with anything other which comes to my mind". Then I started to look at C++'s unwieldiness with more tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from some syntax troubles, your code does work.
But it's kinda tacky. Enums are ints, but stylewise, you should stick to values that are actually in the enumeration.

Maybe use a different int for the bitwise-collection. & be careful to assign powers of 2, I guess. If you really want a bitwise set.

```
typedef enum Options
{
Surf     = 0x01,
Out      = 0x02
} Options;
```

Answer (score 0):

enums are just placeholders for int values so when you bitwise or them you get this : in binary (4 bit representation so its easier for me):
0001 | 0010 = 0011 or 3. Enums can be any value even completely invalid ones.

Answer (score 0):

You might get away with assigning an arbitrary integer value to an `enum` type variable, but it's bad style. As always, code for readability first, and the compiler second. The expectation is that an enum variable will only hold valid enumeration constants.

I would change the last line to:

```
int all = ( Surf | Out);
```